# AsyncTask to call web service returns null value

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, android-asynctask, xmlhttprequest

Ok so I have an instance of AsyncTask which is supposed to call a web service and return the results of an XML file however every time I execute the code I receive a null value at every occurrence of 'string' and I'm not sure exactly how this can be corrected.

The XML file is valid:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31771876/GetPhoneSettings-ST-rsp-eng.xml

but I cannot seem to get data from it.

It's causing a null pointer exception - and I'm trying to nail down it's origin.

LOGCAT:

```
08-14 13:45:10.189: E/STDataSettings(784): java.lang.ClassCastException: libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
08-14 13:45:10.189: W/System.err(784): java.lang.ClassCastException: libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
08-14 13:45:10.189: W/System.err(784):  at com.project.new.datasettings.UpdateActivity$NetworkTask.getQueryResults(UpdateActivity.java:355)
08-14 13:45:10.189: W/System.err(784):  at com.project.new.datasettings.UpdateActivity$NetworkTask.doInBackground(UpdateActivity.java:257)
08-14 13:45:10.189: W/System.err(784):  at com.project.new.datasettings.UpdateActivity$NetworkTask.doInBackground(UpdateActivity.java:1)
08-14 13:45:10.189: W/System.err(784):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
08-14 13:45:10.199: W/System.err(784):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
08-14 13:45:10.199: W/System.err(784):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
08-14 13:45:10.209: W/System.err(784):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
08-14 13:45:10.269: W/System.err(784):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
08-14 13:45:10.331: W/System.err(784):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-14 13:45:10.331: V/STDataSettings(784): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-14 13:45:10.379: W/System.err(784): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-14 13:45:10.389: W/System.err(784):  at java.io.FilterInputStream.available(FilterInputStream.java:53)
08-14 13:45:10.549: W/System.err(784):  at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:234)
08-14 13:45:10.549: W/System.err(784):  at java.io.BufferedReader.fillBuf(BufferedReader.java:130)
08-14 13:45:10.549: W/System.err(784):  at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:354)
08-14 13:45:10.549: W/System.err(784):  at com.project.new.datasettings.UpdateActivity$NetworkTask.doInBackground(UpdateActivity.java:262)
08-14 13:45:10.549: W/System.err(784):  at com.project.new.datasettings.UpdateActivity$NetworkTask.doInBackground(UpdateActivity.java:1)
08-14 13:45:10.549: W/System.err(784):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
08-14 13:45:10.559: W/System.err(784):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
08-14 13:45:10.559: W/System.err(784):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
08-14 13:45:10.559: W/System.err(784):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
08-14 13:45:10.621: W/System.err(784):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
08-14 13:45:10.689: W/System.err(784):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-14 13:45:16.224: V/In the parser(784): now
08-14 13:45:16.229: W/System.err(784): org.xml.sax.SAXException: No input specified.
08-14 13:45:16.239: W/System.err(784):  at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:288)
08-14 13:45:16.239: W/System.err(784):  at com.project.new.datasettings.XmlParserHandlerFinal.getQueryResponse(XmlParserHandlerFinal.java:169)
08-14 13:45:16.239: W/System.err(784):  at com.project.new.datasettings.UpdateActivity.success(UpdateActivity.java:426)
08-14 13:45:16.249: W/System.err(784):  at com.project.new.datasettings.UpdateActivity$NetworkTask.onPostExecute(UpdateActivity.java:399)
08-14 13:45:16.249: W/System.err(784):  at com.project.new.datasettings.UpdateActivity$NetworkTask.onPostExecute(UpdateActivity.java:1)
08-14 13:45:16.249: W/System.err(784):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
08-14 13:45:16.249: W/System.err(784):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
08-14 13:45:16.249: W/System.err(784):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
08-14 13:45:16.249: W/System.err(784):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-14 13:45:16.249: W/System.err(784):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-14 13:45:16.249: W/System.err(784):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-14 13:45:16.249: W/System.err(784):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 13:45:16.262: W/System.err(784):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-14 13:45:16.262: W/System.err(784):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-14 13:45:16.262: W/System.err(784):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-14 13:45:16.269: W/System.err(784):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-14 13:45:16.319: D/MDN(784): 310260
08-14 13:45:16.319: D/mdn1(784): 526
08-14 13:45:16.329: D/mdn2(784): 251
08-14 13:45:16.339: D/ICCID(784): 89014103211118510720
08-14 13:45:16.339: I/System.out(784): ICCID%1234 = 464
08-14 13:45:16.339: I/System.out(784): ICCID/1234 = 72134605519544984
08-14 13:45:16.339: V/In the parser(784): now
08-14 13:45:16.349: W/System.err(784): org.xml.sax.SAXException: No input specified.
08-14 13:45:16.359: W/System.err(784):  at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:288)
08-14 13:45:16.359: W/System.err(784):  at com.project.new.datasettings.XmlParserHandlerFinal.getQueryResponse(XmlParserHandlerFinal.java:169)
08-14 13:45:16.359: W/System.err(784):  at com.project.new.datasettings.ConfigFinalActivity.onCreate(ConfigFinalActivity.java:214)
08-14 13:45:16.359: W/System.err(784):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-14 13:45:16.359: W/System.err(784):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-14 13:45:16.359: W/System.err(784):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-14 13:45:16.359: W/System.err(784):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-14 13:45:16.369: W/System.err(784):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-14 13:45:16.379: W/System.err(784):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-14 13:45:16.379: W/System.err(784):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-14 13:45:16.379: W/System.err(784):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-14 13:45:16.379: W/System.err(784):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-14 13:45:16.379: W/System.err(784):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 13:45:16.379: W/System.err(784):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-14 13:45:16.379: W/System.err(784):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-14 13:45:16.391: W/System.err(784):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-14 13:45:16.399: W/System.err(784):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-14 13:45:27.959: D/dalvikvm(784): GC_CONCURRENT freed 352K, 36% free 4720K/7304K, paused 7ms+5ms, total 51ms
08-14 13:45:27.959: D/dalvikvm(784): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 30ms
08-14 13:45:28.029: D/dalvikvm(784): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 409K, 33% free 4932K/7304K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
08-14 13:45:28.299: D/dalvikvm(784): GC_CONCURRENT freed 625K, 31% free 5111K/7304K, paused 76ms+101ms, total 229ms
08-14 13:45:28.309: I/Choreographer(784): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-14 13:45:29.879: I/System.out(784): DEBUG THIS
08-14 13:45:29.879: D/AndroidRuntime(784): Shutting down VM
08-14 13:45:29.879: W/dalvikvm(784): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
08-14 13:45:29.940: E/AndroidRuntime(784): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-14 13:45:29.940: E/AndroidRuntime(784): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-14 13:45:29.940: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at com.project.new.datasettings.ConfigFinalActivity.showNotification(ConfigFinalActivity.java:533)
08-14 13:45:29.940: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at com.project.new.datasettings.ConfigFinalActivity.onClick(ConfigFinalActivity.java:644)
08-14 13:45:29.940: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
08-14 13:45:29.940: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
08-14 13:45:29.940: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-14 13:45:29.940: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-14 13:45:29.940: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-14 13:45:29.940: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-14 13:45:29.940: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 13:45:29.940: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-14 13:45:29.940: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-14 13:45:29.940: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-14 13:45:29.940: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-14 13:45:33.651: I/Process(784): Sending signal. PID: 784 SIG: 9
```

SOURCE:

```
public class UpdateActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    public static ArrayList<String> NameArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> ValueArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> nameArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> ApnArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmscArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmsportArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmsproxyArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> portArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> proxyArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static int count;
    AlertDialog mErrorAlert = null;
    int version;
    public static int TotalSteps = 8;
    private TelephonyManager tm;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "STDataSettings";
    private Button mUpdateButton = null;
    private Button mAssistUpdateButton = null;
    private Button mAssistInstrButton = null;
    private TextView mReadAgainButton = null;
    private int mInstructionNumber = 0;
    AlertDialog mConfirmAlert = null;
    public static InputStream stream = null;
    public static XmlParserHandlerFinal handler;
    private NetworkTask task;
    private AnimationDrawable loadingAnimation;
    private static final String TAG = "UpdateActivity";
    Context ctx;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // instance for xml parser class
        handler = new XmlParserHandlerFinal();
        handler.setContext(this.getBaseContext());
        tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        int networkType = tm.getNetworkType();
        int phoneType = tm.getPhoneType();
        version = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        // to get MDN(MCC+MNC) of the provider of the SIM and ICCID (Serial
        // number of the SIM)
        // and to check for the Carrier type

        task = new NetworkTask();
        if (phoneType == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA
                || (phoneType != TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM
                && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS
                && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE
                && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA
                && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA
                && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP
                && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA
                && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS && networkType != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE)) {
            // If the phone type is CDMA or
            // the phone phone type is not GSM and the network type is none of
            // the network types indicated in the statement
            // Display incompatibility message
            showAlert(getString(R.string.incomp_sm_dialog));
            // Network type is looked because some tablets have no phone type.
            // We rely on network type in such cases
        } else if (!(tm.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT
                || (tm.getSimOperator())
                .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo)) || (tm
                        .getSimOperator()).equals(getString(R.string.numeric_att)))) {
            // if SIM is present and is NOT a T-Mo network SIM,
            // display Error message alert indicating to use SM SIM
            showAlert(getString(R.string.insert_sm_dialog));
        }// No SIM or SIM with T-Mo MNC MCC present
        else if (version < VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            // Initial UI setup for versions lower than ICS
            setContentView(R.layout.update);
            mUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_button);

            mUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        } else {// ICS and up

            // task.execute();

            if ((tm.getSimOperator()).equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo))
                    || (tm.getSimOperator())
                    .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_att))) {
                // Update APN table in separate thread
                task.execute("");

                // Device has T-Mo network SIM card MCC and MNC correctly
                // populated
                // Reduce number of steps to 6
                TotalSteps = 6;
            }

        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == mUpdateButton) {
            // Update button for versions lower than ICS is selected
            // setContentView(R.layout.updating);
            onClickMethod(v);

            Intent i = new Intent(this, ConfigFinalActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        } else if (v == mAssistUpdateButton) {

            // Update button for ICS and up is selected
            // Get the TextView in the Assist Update UI
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.apn_app_text_cta2);
            String text = "";
            CharSequence styledText = text;
            switch (mInstructionNumber) {
            case 0:
                // Retrieve the instruction string resource corresponding the
                // 2nd set of instructions
                text = String.format(getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr),
                        TotalSteps);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
                // Update the TextView with the correct set of instructions
                tv.setText(styledText);
                // Increment instruction number so the correct instructions
                // string resource can be retrieve the next time the update
                // button is pressed
                mInstructionNumber++;
                break;
            case 1:
                text = getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr2);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
                tv.setText(styledText);
                // Increment instruction number so the correct instructions
                // string resource can be retrieve the next time the update
                // button is pressed
                mInstructionNumber++;
                break;
            case 2:
                // Final set of instructions-Change to the corresponding layout

                setContentView(R.layout.assist_instructions);
                String assistUpdateInstr = String.format(
                        getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr3), TotalSteps);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(assistUpdateInstr);
                TextView assistInstrText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.updated_text);
                assistInstrText.setText(styledText);
                mAssistInstrButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_instr_btn);
                mReadAgainButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.read_again_btn);
                mAssistInstrButton.setOnClickListener(this);
                mReadAgainButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
        } else if (v == mAssistInstrButton) {
            // "LET'S DO THIS" Button in final instructions screen for ICS and
            // up is selected
            // Create ConfigActivity Intent
            Intent i = new Intent(this, ConfigFinalActivity.class);
            // Invoke ConfigActivity Intent to start the assisted update
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        } else if (v == mReadAgainButton) {
            // go back to 1st set of instructions if read again is selected
            mInstructionNumber = 0;
            setContentView(R.layout.assist_update);
            String assistUpdate = getString(R.string.apn_app_text_cta2);
            CharSequence styledText = Html.fromHtml(assistUpdate);
            TextView assistText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.apn_app_text_cta2);
            assistText.setText(styledText);
            mAssistUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_update_btn);
            mAssistUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    public void onClickMethod(View v) {
        mUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.drawable.btn_update_active_hdpi);

    }

    private void showAlert(String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(message).setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                UpdateActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
        mConfirmAlert = builder.create();
        mConfirmAlert.show();
    }

    // AsyncTask to call web service
    class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, InputStream> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected InputStream doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                // saving the response in InputStream
                stream = getQueryResults("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31771876/GetPhoneSettings-ST-rsp-eng.xml");
                // stream = new BufferedInputStream(https.getInputStream());
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(stream);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(in));
                String strLine;
                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) { // Print the content
                    // on the console
                    System.out.println(strLine);
                    in.close();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {

                Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SAXException e) {

                Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // The code below plays a Simple Promo animation

            for (int incr = 0; incr < 2; incr++) {
                // Sleep for 1/2 second
                // Invoke UI to change updating text to show 1 dot
                // And Increasing the level to reduce the amount of clipping and
                // slowly reveals the hand image
                publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty,
                        R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                try {
                    // Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                }
                publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_empty,
                        R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                try {
                    // Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                }
                publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_empty, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                try {
                    // Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                }
                publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_empty);
                try {
                    // Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                }
                publishProgress(R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full,
                        R.drawable.loading_full, R.drawable.loading_full);

                // Sleep for 1/2 second
                try {
                    // Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                }
            }
            return stream;
        }

        /*
         * Sends a query to server and gets back the parsed results in a bundle
         * urlQueryString - URL for calling the webservice
         */
        protected synchronized InputStream getQueryResults(String urlQueryString)
                throws IOException, SAXException, SSLException,
                SocketTimeoutException, Exception {
            // HttpsURLConnection https = null;

            HttpsURLConnection https = null;
            String uri = urlQueryString;

            URL urlo = new URL(uri);

            try {
                https = (HttpsURLConnection) urlo.openConnection();
                https.setConnectTimeout(20000); // 20 second timeout
                https.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

                if ("gzip".equals(https.getContentEncoding())) {
                    stream = new GZIPInputStream(stream);
                } else
                    stream = https.getInputStream();

            } catch (SSLException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();

            } finally {
                // https.disconnect();
            }

            return stream;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

            // Call function to update image view

            setProgressImgView(progress[0], progress[1]);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(InputStream stream) {
            super.onPostExecute(stream);
            // This method is called to parse the response and save the
            // ArrayLists
            success();

        }

    }

    private void setProgressImgView(Integer textViewId, Integer imageViewId) {
        // update image view with the updating dots
        // Reset view layout in case orientation while updating
        // setContentView(R.layout.updating);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();

        if (mErrorAlert != null)
            mErrorAlert.dismiss();
    }

    public void success() {

        // to parse the response
        try {
            handler.getQueryResponse(stream);

        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // to set method to save the ArryaLists from the parser
        setArrayList();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ConfigFinalActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();

    }

    // method to save the ArrayLists from parser
    public static void setArrayList() {
        nameArr = handler.getnameArr();
        ApnArr = handler.getApnArr();
        mmscArr = handler.getMMSCArr();
        mmsproxyArr = handler.getMmscProxyArr();
        mmsportArr = handler.getMmsPortArr();
        proxyArr = handler.getMmscProxyArr();
        portArr = handler.getMmsPortArr();
        count = handler.getCount();
        // System.out.println("testing123");

        for (int i = 0; i < nameArr.size() - 1; i++) {
            System.out.println(nameArr.get(i));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < ApnArr.size() - 1; i++) {
            System.out.println(ApnArr.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you retrieve the return statement?

Comment: I suggest to check internet permissions first.
Also please show us the logs printed in the console

Comment: 1. What does "getQueryResults" do?
2. You shouldn't return an input stream from the doInBackground method.
3. You close the stream if you can read from it.
4. You really don't need all those "Thread.sleep(500);" lines

Comment: The quality of this code is pretty horrendous. Please clean it up and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: 1. getQueryResults requests an HTTPS input stream 2. Ok - I'll remove it 3. Check out my full source I just posted - are you still sure? If so - I'll try removing it. 4. I just removed them :)

Comment: @ Ghaleb Khaled - I added the logcat above and I have the internet permission enabled:  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: Any suggestions at this point? (I'm still stuck on this issue)